# How to Rectify the Relationship Fault in CoreData While parsing RESTKIT?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, relationship

I want to Store the `EY_ConnectionUsage` Entity value to the `EY_Connection` entity Cell.I have Added two Entities with Attributes and Created Relationship with name `usageData`.But this Shows error "<'usageData' Relationship Fault>".This is a Method I wrote to map the RESTKIT value to CoreData.

DataAccessHandler.m

```
+(void)createConnectionMappingWithStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore saveInDelegate:(AppDelegate *)appDelegate{

NSLog(@"appdele==>>%@",appDelegate);
RKEntityMapping *connectionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"EY_Connections" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
connectionMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"connectionNumber"];
[connectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"ServiceNo" : @"connectionServiceNumber", @"Name" : @"connectionName", @"Region" : @"connectionRegion", @"Phase" : @"connectionPhase",
    @"Circle" : @"connectionCircle", @"Section" : @"connectionSection", @"Load" : @"connectionLoad",
    @"Distribution" : @"connectionDistribution", @"MeterNo" : @"connectionMeterNumber", @"ConnectionNumber" : @"connectionNumber", @"Address" : @"connectionAddress", @"ServiceStatus" : @"connectionStatus"}];



RKEntityMapping *connectionUsageMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"EY_ConnectionUsage" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
connectionUsageMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"usageAssessmentDate"];
[connectionUsageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"assessment_date" : @"usageAssessmentDate", @"reading" : @"usageReading", @"units" : @"usageUnits", @"amount" : @"usageAmount",
                                                         @"payment_date" : @"usagePaymentDate", @"status" : @"usageStatus"}];

[connectionMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"usage" toKeyPath:@"usageData" withMapping:connectionUsageMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *articleListResponseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:connectionMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:@"user_history/consumer/data.json"
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)
 ];

[appDelegate createObjectManagerForurl:@"http://sciflare.com/energyly/api/" andAddResponseDescriptor:articleListResponseDescriptor];
[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <'usageData' Relationship Fault>

This means that the relationship data hasn't been loaded yet, because you haven't tried to use it. Logging the object isn't enough to load the data. The whole point of the faulting system is to prevent too much data being loaded into memory at the same time.

So, basically, it isn't a problem that it's a fault. When you try to use it the data will be populated and everything will be fine.

Comment: I am Having `usageAssesmentDate` attribute in `EY_ConnectionUsage`.how can i use this attribute. I have created a object for EY_Connections and if i use `objectname.usageAssesmentData` its not coming.I can only able to access the usageData that too not showing the values..

Comment: what is `objectname` ? how did you create it ? you may benefit from trace logging to see exactly what is received and mapped

Comment: How to do trace logging?

Answer (score 0):

CoreData says that 'load only needed data'. If we are trying to fetch unwanted data then coredata shows 'FAULT'.

Foe more detail please go through [CoreData Fault](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-a-core-data-fault--cms-25157?utm_source=Tuts%20&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=relatedtutorials&utm_content=sidebar&WT.mc_id=Tuts%20_website_relatedtutorials_sidebar)

Comment: Small Doubt.Am Having Attribute Values in mappingResult.How to populate these values in nextViewController while clicking a button....Nearly am having 1o attributes...

Comment: I am not aware about your data structure but when you are moving to next screen, try to populate all data on a next screen viewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear.